# Moving folder content to parent folder

Tags: windows-7, powershell

This is my current folder structure in a Windows 7 machine:

```
---myfoolder
   |    
   +---nope              
   |   \---nope          
   |           nope.txt  
   |                     
   +---wtf               
   |   \---wtf           
   |           wtf.txt   
   |                     
   +---yep               
   |   \---yep           
   |           yep.txt   
   |                     
   \---zomg              
       \---zomg          
               zomg.txt
```

In this structure there is a duplicate folder at each layer like `nope\nope`.

I'd like to move each file in each folder up a level to eliminate this duplicate (note that for the sake of simplicity I've listed 1 file in each directory but there could be multiple files with different extensions).

This is what I've tried with powershell [from this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/373589/how-can-i-move-files-from-2-level-folders-to-1-level-folder):

```
gci -R | ?{!$_.PSIsContainer} | %{mv $_.fullname $_.directory.parent}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting this error:

```
mv : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At line:1 char:35
+ gci -R | ?{!$_.PSIsContainer} | %{mv $_.fullname $_.directory.parent}
```

I think something fishy is happening because there is a duplicate name between parent and child folder, I've tried also providing a `-Force` in the `mv` statement but it only managed to actually erase the files leaving the folders as they are (luckly enough I had setup a test environment before doing this!).

What am I missing? Unfortunately I'm really a novice in PS scripting, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Move-Item` takes paths as strings, and when `.directory.parent` casts to a string, it's either an empty string or just one directory name, it doesn't seem to be the full path to the parent folder.

Try:

```
$_.directory.parent.FullName
```

or

```
|%{ mv $_.FullName (Split-Path -Parent $_.Directory) }
```

Comment: Yea I figured it out myself a bit after I posted my question, but you explained pretty well thank you!